# Find the length of a rectangle when provided with area and perimeter only

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve for the length of a rectangle when provided with an area and a perimeter. Something like `rectangle(14, 10)`(perimeter, area) outputting 5 because it is a 2x5 rectangle. Mathematically, solving the resulting quadratic equation would have been the answer. However, I can't think of a way I would do this programmatically. Help with the pseudocode for the resulting algorithm will be appreciated. The solution is written in python.

Forgot to add. What if I'm not supposed to import math or cmath? How would the solution look then?

Comment: Share the quadratic equation and perhaps someone might be able to help you to code the solution to your homework question

Comment: Make sure that you understand the math well enough that you can write a *formula* for the length as a function of the area and perimeter, and not just in a special case. If you get to that stage, it should be easy enough to implement your formula in code. For something this simple, there really isn't much difference between solving it mathematically and solving it programmatically, though your entire question seems to be predicated on there being a substantial difference.

Comment: @JohnColeman That's true. I was thinking I'd have to break it down in a different way for my code solution. From trincot's solution below I realised I was overthinking the code implementation. Thanks for the help. I have a better eye in spotting similar problems now.

Answer (score 3):

You'll just have to implement the solution to the quadratic equation:

```
def rectangle(perimeter, area):
    return (perimeter + (perimeter ** 2 - 16 * area) ** 0.5) / 4

print(rectangle(14, 10))  # 5.0
```

The quadratic equation to solve is derived like this, where we have p[erimeter], a[rea], w[idth] and h[eight]:

*p = 2(w + h)*
    *a = wh*

Substitute *w* by *a / h* in the first equation:

*p = 2(a/h + h)*, or
    *ph = 2a + 2h²*, or
    *2h² - ph + 2a = 0*

Discriminant of this quadratic equation in *h*, is *p² - 16a*, and one of the solutions is thus:

*h = [ p + √(p² - 16a) ] / 4*

...which is what you find implemented in the above code.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. I forgot to add that I couldn't import sqrt. Unless there's no other way to do it then I'll just do the import and hope the instructor understands.

Comment: You can use `** 0.5` instead. Updated.

Comment: You're the best man. Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 0):

Per the definition of a rectangle, lets label the primary side (larger or equal to latter) as "Width of Rectangle" and the secondary one as the "Length of the Rectangle". Both of them are positive real numbers. The special case of length equaling rectangle yields a square.
By this description; per mathematical definition the area of a rectangle is the multiplication of the length and width whereas the perimeter is the doubling of the sum of length and width.

Lets put these into a more formal definitions by some labeling as:
A: Area
P: Perimeter
W: Width
L: Length

Given your problem definition, the area and perimeter are know we need to able to derive the measurement for the sides from them. To this end lets express the definitions written above in a more formal way as below:

```
A = W x L ......... (1.1)
P = 2 x (W + L) ... (1.2)
```

As we have two unknowns and two known variables in, we should be able to derive the values for W and L through the use of quadratic identities.
Identities:

```
(W + L)^2 = W^2 + 2 x (W X L) + L^2 ... (2.1)
(W - L)^2 = W^2 - 2 x (W X L) + L^2 ... (2.2)
```

Inserting 1.1 and 1.2 into 2.1 with some house-keeping yields:

```
1/4 x P^2 = W^2 + L^2 + 2 x A ... (3.1)
W^2 + L^2 = 1/4 x P^2 - 2 x A ... (3.2)
```

and inserting 1.1 and 1.2 into 2.2 with some house-keeping yields:

```
(W - L)^2 = W^2 + L^2 - 2 x A ....... (4.1)
W - L = (W^2 + L^2 - 2 x A)^(1/2) ... (4.2)
```

Inserting 3.2 into 4.2 yields the difference equation for the measures of the sides as:

```
W - L = (1/4 x P^2 - 2 x A - 2 x A)^(1/2) ... (5.1)
W - L = (1/4 x P^2 - 4 x A)^(1/2) ... (5.2)
```

The sum of 5.2 and 1.2 halved yields 6.1, 6.2, 6.3 and 6.4 in sequence:

```
(5.2) + 1/2 x (1.2) ................................... (6.1)
(W - L) + (W + L) = (1/4 x P^2 - 4 x A)^(1/2) + P/2 ... (6.2)
2 x W = (1/4 x P^2 - 4 x A)^(1/2) + P/2 ............... (6.3)
W = P/4 + (1/16 x P^2 - A)^(1/2) ...................... (6.4)
```

Subtracting 6.4 from 1.2 halved should yield the equation for L as follows:

```
(1.2)/2 - (6.4) ...................................... (7.1)
W + L - W = P/2 - ( P/4 + (1/16 x P^2 - A)^(1/2) ) ... (7.2)
L = P/4 - (1/16 x P^2 - A)^(1/2) ..................... (7.3)
```

So in the end we get the equations to calculate W and L as given in 6.4 and 7.3.
In Python 3; we can implement this as a function with Width and Length returned as a tuple:

```
def retrieveRectangleWidthAndLengthFromPerimeterAndArea(_P, _A):
  _W = _P/4 + ((_P**2)/16-_A)**0.5;
  _L = _P/4 - ((_P**2)/16-_A)**0.5;
  return _W, _L;

print( retrieveRectangleWidthAndLengthFromPerimeterAndArea(14, 10) );
```